# Avoid python module statements with pytest mocks

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have some settings in a file, which read from my environment:

## File1.py

```
set1 = os.getenv(...)

SETTINGS = {
  key1: set1,
  ...
}
```

In another File, I am importing them:

## File2.py

```
from File1 import SETTINGS

MyClass():
  ...
```

In my tests file, I am mocking the MyClass methods, however, it is trying to access env vars, due to previous imports.

Is there anyway I can mock File2 imports?

This is my tests file:

## Tests.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest

from File2 import MyClass

@patch.object(
    MyClass,
    "my_method",
    return_value=None,
)
def test_my_test(mock1):
  my_class = MyClass()
  ....
```

**Summary**: How do I avoid the os.getenv() for my tests?

Comment: Do you need to avoid it or can you just set an environment variable in your conftest?

Comment: Didnt know I could use conftest for that purpose, I think it might work

Comment: Sure, `os.environ["var"] = "foo"` should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to avoid it, you could set a value for the environment variable in your `conftest.py` file which would allow you to test closer to the actual code.

```
import os
os.environ["var"] = "foo"
```